# R dbplyr SQL date filter issue

Tags: r, sql-server, dbplyr

I've connected to a SQL Server database with the code shown here, and then I try to run a query to collect data filtered on a date, which is held as an integer in the table in YYYYMMDD format

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), driver = "SQL Server", server = "***")
fact_transaction_line <- tbl(con,in_schema('***', '***'))

data <- fact_transaction_line %>% 
  filter(key_date_trade == 20200618)
```

This stores as a query, but fails when I use glimpse to look at the data, with the below error

> "dbplyr_031"
>   WHERE ("key_date_trade" = 20200618.0)'

Why isn't this working, is there a better way for me to format the query to get this data?

Comment: have you tried the `collect` function? It will collect the results of your query you can also use `show_query` to see what is happening behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

Both `fact_transaction_line` and `data` in your example code are remote tables. One important consequence of this is that you are limited to interacting with them to certain dplyr commands. `glimpse` may not be a command that is supported for remote tables.

What you can do instead (including @Bruno's suggestions):

1. Use `head` to view the top few rows of your remote data.
2. If you are receiving errors, try `show_query(data)` to see the underlying SQL query for the remote table. Check that this query is correct.
3. Check the size of the remote table with `remote_table%>% ungroup() %>% summarise(num = n())`. If the remote table is small enough to fit into your local R memory, then `local_table = collect(remote_table)` will copy the table into R memory.
4. Combine options 1 & 3: `local_table = data %>% head(100) %>% collect()` will load the first 100 rows of your remote table into R. Then you can `glimpse(local_table)`.